# What direction does a ball move whose axis of spin is neither parallel nor orthogonal to a flat surface?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

Assume non-slip conditions on a flat surface. Assuming that a ball starts from a standstill, and starts spinning of its own accord, what's the relationship between the translational direction a ball moves and its axis of spin? (Think in terms of the BB-8 droid from Star Wars.)

Google searches have shown me nothing other than simplistic situations where the axis of spin is perfectly parallel to the ground and orthogonal to the ball's direction of motion.

Comment: But how can that be? A ball spinning about an axis parallel to the ground will roll along the ground orthogonal to the spin axis. And a ball spinning about a vertical axis spins in place. So there's got to be some kind of connection.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your *non-slip conditions* caveat there. But the question is far too generic. You need to specify the conditions of rotation and translation more in order to get ameaningful answer to your question. Friction forces between ball and surface will cause both *angular* and *translational* accelerations/deccelerations that affect the state of motion of the ball. But there's no general *relationship between the translational direction a ball moves and its axis of spin*, it's very case-specific.

Comment: Okay, I'll append to my original details of the question. Please let me know if they don't suffice.

Comment: Ok, post a comment like 'edit made' and I''ll try and have a look at the  edited question and maybe answer it. Or post a new question altogether...

Comment: Thanks Gert. I edited last night. If it's still unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Perhaps what you are describing is a spinning top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the thing you are describing looks like this:

[image]

Now the point where the ball touches the surface has a velocity $v=\omega r'$. We can compute the linear distance $r'$ from $R$ and $\theta$:

$$r' = R\sin\theta$$

If the angular velocity is constant, the ball will run in a straight line, with velocity $v=R\omega\sin\theta$ in a direction perpendicular to the plane of the paper as drawn here (plane that includes both the axis of rotation and the contact point).

The first improvement to that simple model would take into account that the contact will not be a "point", but rather an "area". As drawn, points to the right of the contact "point" will be moving faster, and points to the right will be moving slower, than the central point. This results in a torque about the vertical axis, which will appear anticlockwise if viewed from the top.

When you add that vector to the vector of the rotation, it tends to cancel the vertical component - meaning that over time, the sphere will start to rotate more about the horizontal axis. Of course if there is a contact area there will be a general slowing down of the rotation (heat dissipation due to friction because not all contact points travel at the same speed).

It gets more interesting if the ball "starts to rotate" from a stationary position, because then the net force on the ball (not through the center of mass) will create a torque that will cause precession of the axis of rotation - in the diagram as drawn, the axis of rotation will tilt towards the observer, so as the ball rolls away from you it would appear to swerve to the right.

Peripherally related: this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSFYwDDVgac) of a concept for a new spherical wheel...

Comment: Thanks for the excellent, detailed answer! My takeaway from this is that, given the conditions I described above, the ball will always roll in the direction orthogonal to its axis of rotation; and that frictional (right?) torque tilts the vertical plane of this axis away from the original "forward" direction when accelerating from a standstill. Very interesting...

Comment: I think you have to show that the angular acceleration is indeed zero. I don't think it is obvious. You can show that no lateral acceleration by implying that friction is applied in-line with the motion only, but for angular acceleration things are more complicated. Also the general case has some slip initially and eventually it transitions into rolling.

Comment: @ja72 - not sure I understand what case you are talking about. OP specified "no slip", and if you have an internal mechanism (counter rotating flywheel) you can indeed accelerate without any slip.

Comment: Like I said: "In the general case.."